# oozie job status always shows 50%, if i run sample oozie workflow also same in my cloudera quickstart vm? why?

Tags: hadoop, scheduled-tasks, oozie, hadoop2, oozie-coordinator

i am trying to run simple oozie jobs which are given as demo in cloudera quickstart  usr/share/doc/oozie-4.1.0+cdh5.10.0+389/oozie-examples.tar.gz ,when i tried to run it runs and create a job but when i see the job status it shows always 50% i dont know why its happening. can anyone help on this please.

workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="java-main-wf">
    <start to="java-node"/>
    <action name="java-node">
        <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <main-class>org.apache.oozie.example.DemoJavaMain</main-class>
            <arg>Hello</arg>
            <arg>Oozie!</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Java failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
============================================

job.properties

nameNode=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/demo/${examplesRoot}/apps/java-main

================================================
cli run

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ oozie job -oozie http://quickstart.cloudera:11000/oozie -config /home/cloudera/Desktop/job.properties -run
job: 0000001-170507215637609-oozie-oozi-W
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ oozie job -oozie http://quickstart.cloudera:11000/oozie -info 0000000-170507215637609-oozie-oozi-W
Job ID : 0000000-170507215637609-oozie-oozi-W
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workflow Name : java-main-wf
App Path      : hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/demo/examples/apps/java-main
Status        : RUNNING
Run           : 0
User          : cloudera
Group         : -
Created       : 2017-05-08 05:23 GMT
Started       : 2017-05-08 05:23 GMT
Last Modified : 2017-05-08 05:23 GMT
Ended         : -
CoordAction ID: -

Actions
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                                                                            Status    Ext ID                 Ext Status Err Code
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000-170507215637609-oozie-oozi-W@java-node                                PREP      -                      -          -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000-170507215637609-oozie-oozi-W@:start:                                  OK        -                      OK         -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


please help. i tried 100 of sample workflow all will run successfully and creates a job id and status of job will be always 50%
```

Comment: Can you check, you have correct value for Resource Manager address. `jobTracker=localhost:8021`

Comment: What do you see in the Yarn UI? Any chance that the job is submitted but cannot start _(e.g. shitty sandbox environment with not enough RAM to start a single job)_?